# Running specs by tag

Tags: python, testing, jasmine, protractor, nose

In Python and `nosetests` testing framework there is this idea of [tagging your tests](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html):

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

@attr(speed='slow')
def test_big_download():
    ...
```

and running the tests that have only specific tags:

```
nosetests -a speed=slow
```

This is very helpful when there is a need to run tests from a specific category or type.

Is there anything similar in **`protractor` + `jasmine`**?

---

The closest functionality I've found is the [`'grep' option`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/0b930035905d1868225667de358222e51394f3ac) introduced in `1.6.0`:

```
protractor conf.js --grep='pattern to match'
```

Comment: tags are the closest you can get to because there are no annotations in js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep is the closest you can get to this because there are **no annotations in js**.