# Group based testing in protractor and jasmine as we do it using TestNG

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor

We  group Test case in TestNG using.

```
@Test( groups = {"xyz", "test" })
@Test( groups = {"Testing" })
```

If we call this in  xml configuration it will run only that group test cases, reaming won't execute . BY calling it in XML as shown below.

```
<groups>
<run>
    <include name="Testing"/>
</run>
```

.

Like this is there any behavior available in Jasmine Framework for grouping test cases with out writing test cases in separate place.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there are *no annotations in javascript*.

It sounds like you are asking about the concept of [`suites`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/docs/page-objects.md#configuring-test-suites) in `Protractor`:

```
suites: {
    homepage: 'tests/e2e/homepage/**/*Spec.js',
    search: [
        'tests/e2e/contact_search/**/*Spec.js',
        'tests/e2e/venue_search/**/*Spec.js'
    ]
},
```

It allows to have user-defined sets of tests grouped logically which you can run separately:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --suite homepage
```

---

There is also a `grep` option, see:

- [Running specs by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256947/running-specs-by-tag)

Comment: Suites will execute different spec that  I know.
Inside each spec we need to group test cases which we do in Testng.

Comment: @Naveen well, you can have nested describe blocks which can help to group it blocks inside..then, use the `grep` option to run the specific groups..just thoughts.

Comment: I am not that good in jasmine. I need some functionality like this               http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#groups-of-groups