# Grunt uitest: Test only specific feature

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jasmine, protractor

I know there is a way you can modify the localConfig.json file and by adding something like "tag":"name", in feature files you will be able to write @name and test ONLY this feature.

How does it work?

Comment: fwiw, you can disable a suite by using `xdescribe` in Jasmine. http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Disabling_Suites

Comment: I am working with >60 files, so thats not effective at all.
There is this "@Name" thing which makes it a lot easier, just don´t remember the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so apparently nobody knows this (simple) solution I found out by myself now:

1: Go to localConfig.json

2: Write "testSuiteTags": ["@YourName"]

3: Place @YourName (tag) right before specific scenario in .feature file-

That´s it

Answer (score 0):

There are no annotations in javascript.

You have several options here:

- use [`suites`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/docs/page-objects.md#configuring-test-suites) (recommended) to group your tests logically:

  ```
  suites: {
      homepage: 'tests/e2e/homepage/**/*Spec.js',
      search: [
          'tests/e2e/contact_search/**/*Spec.js',
          'tests/e2e/venue_search/**/*Spec.js']
      },
  ```

  And then run, for instance:

  ```
  protractor protractor.conf.js --suite homepage
  ```
- use [`grep` option](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/0b930035905d1868225667de358222e51394f3ac):

  ```
  protractor conf.js --grep='pattern to match'
  ```

See also:

- [Running specs by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256947/running-specs-by-tag)

Comment: This is waaay too complicated for a project with >60 Files. Look at answer for better solution

Comment: @Best_Where_Gives this is actually a practical advice. And we have a project with way more than 60 files. `suites` is a great way to organize your tests into logical groups. Additionally, it does involve editing your 60+ tests at all.