# Cherry pick the tests and create suits

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

Is there a way to cherry pick the tests and create suits in protractor/jasmine e2e test.  I know protractor accepts with wildcard specs (*.spec") in the suites, but I am looking for select few tests in spec files and create a suit to run on protractor. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: basically you want to group `it()`s instead of test files?

Comment: Yes alecxe, is there way to pick them up from different spec files and create a new spec file or  some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*`suites` can only group test files.* Though, I would still think about regrouping the specs inside tests, or splitting them into multiple files so that `suites` can be used here - it is a great way to organize your tests and group them logically.

---

If you want to run specific `it()` blocks/specs from different files as a part of a group - *tag them*:

```
describe("test1", function () {
    it("should test something (#mytag)", function () {

    });
});

describe("test2", function () {
    it("should test something else (#mytag)", function () {

    });
});
```

And run with `--grep`:

```
protractor conf.js --grep "#mytag"
```

See also:

- [Running specs by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256947/running-specs-by-tag)

---

Alternatively, use [*focused specs*](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/focused_specs.html) (`fdescribe`/`fit`, or `ddescribe`/`iit`):

```
describe("test1", function () {
    fit("should test something", function () {

    });
});

describe("test2", function () {
    fit("should test something else", function () {

    });
});
```

Comment: Jasmine2 supports ddescribe() and iit() as well, but I believe they both do the same thing.

Comment: I think --grep is the only way out, basically to categorize test as smokeSpec.js or FullSpec.js

Comment: @Jyothish got it, you cannot use suites currently since you have basically multiple keys to group - functional, smoke, performance etc. Yeah, focused tests is a temporary thing. `grep` may be a good option for you. You can also make a separate group of test files that would "import" (using, for instance,[`require`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423156/getting-requirejs-to-work-with-jasmine)) other tests..this way you may have, say, a directory of smoke tests that would import some of the functional tests..just thoughts.

Comment: @Jyothish this is also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061512/whats-a-good-way-to-reuse-test-code-using-jasmine.

Comment: @alecxe, I don't see --grep as argument to protractor command

Comment: @Jyothish okay, what version are you using?

Comment: @alecxe version 2.2.0

Comment: @Jyothish yeah, the `--help` does not show it, but it's there, please see: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/cli.js#L64.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90447/discussion-between-jyothish-and-alecxe).